# How to stop poll in telebot (PyTelegramBotAPI)

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

I have the program, which sends poll with send_poll function. How can I stop it when time expires and how to get results from it
close_date and open_period params can't help me with it, because they are limited by 600 seconds, but I need to stop it in bigger period of time (month)

```
bot.send_poll(channel, f'Poll content', options=["Yes", "No"])
```

Answer (score 0):

this poll never ends

```
bot.send_poll(channel, f'Poll content', options=["Yes", "No"],open_period=-1)
```